# Can someone explain the logic of this bit of code?

Tags: c

I ran it through an IDE and the remainder values came out 3, 2, 0, 1.
I understand the first remainder, but not the rest.
Also, how come the loop terminates? Isn't x always going to be greater than 0, therefore continuing indefinitely? Thank you.

```
int x = 1023;

while (x > 0)
 {
   printf("%d", x% 10);
   x = x /10;
 }
```

Comment: `x` is divided by `10` in each loop. This is equivalent to shifting the decimal mumber one place to the right, and the loop stops when there is nothing left. Notice the pattern of the output - it is the number in reverse order.

Comment: regarding: `x = x /10;` this is an integer divide.  In such a divide, all fractions are dropped.  so the results of that divide are: 102, 10, 0  the modulo results are 1023%10= 3, 102%10= 2, 10%10= 0, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in C, when both operands of a division have integer type, the division also has an integer type, and the value is the result of division [rounded toward zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic#Division).

So in the first iteration, the statement `x = x /10;` changes `x` from `1023` to `102` (not `102.3`).

Answer (score 0):

since you are dividing integers you are getting rounded results each time,

so each iteration of x becomes

102

10

1

Just print x each time and you will see.
So 102 modulo 10 is 2

10 modul0 10 is 0

1 modulo 10 is 1